# How do you render an array of components in a way that preserves the child component state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Basically, I have one page that consists of three main components. A map, a custom Search box, and a list that shows the selected locations, which is stored in the main component's state. For each location it renders a component (MarkerList) that has its own state and interactivity. These components are created using a .map() function.

The problem arises when a user interacts with the other two components. Any update to the main component's state causes it to create a new array of List components, and thus resets the state of that component. From my understanding this is what .map is supposed to do.

I've tried wrapping the .map in a callback, and that works until the itemList is updated, and then all interactivity with any of the list components is reset because all the components are new. I've also tried to instead render an array of the components instead of using the .map() function to no avail.

```
return (
   <div>
      <TestMap />
      <div>
         <Search items={items} />

         {itemList.map(i =>
            <MarkerList key={uuid()} items={i.items}/>
         )}

      </div>
   </div>
)
```

I've omitted a lot of the styling and props. But the TestMap and Search components but have props which allow them to alter this component's state.

Is there any way to go about rendering the MarkerList components in such a way that they are not destroyed/created on every state change? And would there be any way to "remember" the state for each MarkerList when a new item is added to the itemList?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you're talking about the `itemList` that's what `key` is for. If you provide a new key on every render it'll re-render everything--`uuid()` *appears* to generate a new key each render. A `key` should be stable if the underlying data is stable.

Comment: A state of component should persist between renders. If it doesn't it means you are doing something wrong. As @DaveNewton mentioned, UUID should be generated once, not in every render

Comment: @DaveNewton That was exactly it! Feel little a stupid after that. I had just used uuid() for a long array of basic data, and didn't realize it updated after re-render so thought it was safe to use for this. Guess not. I'll definitely be more conscientious with keys. Thank you for your help!